# rails: changing database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, production-environment

I have created an app using a badly named database, all alterations to important data in the database have been done in fixtures so that I can just drop the database, recreate it and then rake migrate the database tables and fill them with the initial data from the fixtures.

I would like to change the name of my database now, so I  updated the database.yml file to reflect another database name. I created the database in mysql and then tried to run the migration and fixtures.

Running the migration with trace shows that it is running commands to create tables etc. However once I am finished I get errors in my application saying that the tables don't exist in the new database.

I go into mysql and check the database and it is completely empty. I have tried wiping everything and running the migrations a few times but nothing changes. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what commands you used to do the migration, but to migrate a production database (which I infer from the tag, "production-environment"), you have to do:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

If that's not the answer, then please provide the command you used to perform the migration, which database you expected to be affected, and the relevant bits of `database.yml`.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't using the rails_env=production,  earlier I had the prod and dev database as the same one so it must have been filling the data up on the dev database not the prod.